# SHGetFolderPath Returns Local Path but Not when the same Run as Service

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, service

I have following code that is giving Local App Data folder inside the System 32 folder. I have attached the code below:

```
int WriteToLog(const char* str)
{
    FILE* log;
    log = fopen("C:\\lpa\\sample.txt", "a+");
    if (log == NULL)
        return -1;
    fprintf(log, "%s\n", str);
    fclose(log);
    return 0;
}
std::string GetLocalAppDataPath()
{
    HANDLE hfile;
    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
    if(SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,NULL,0, szPath))) 
    {
        std::string path = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(szPath);
        boost::replace_all(path, "\\", "\\\\");
        return path;
    }
}

void LoggingInit()
{
        log4cplus::initialize ();
        helpers::LogLog::getLogLog()->setInternalDebugging(false);
        std::string app_data_path = GetLocalAppDataPath();
        std::string log_folder_path = app_data_path + "\\\\lpa\\\\output\\\\";
        std::string log_file = log_folder_path + "output.log";
        WriteToLog(log_file.c_str());
        SharedAppenderPtr append_1(new RollingFileAppender(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT(log_file), 10*1024*1024, 5));
        append_1->setName(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("LogpointAgentLog"));
        PatternLayout *p = new PatternLayout(LOG4CPLUS_TEXT("[%D] <%-5p> [%F : %L] %m%n"));
        append_1->setLayout(std::auto_ptr<Layout>(p));
        Logger::getRoot().addAppender(append_1);
        root = Logger::getRoot();
        WriteToLog("Loging Init Successful");
        //std::string path = GetRegistryPath();
        //WriteToLog(path.c_str());
}
```

When I create run program using making a service, I don't get the true Local App Data Path.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    WriteToLog("Logging Init");
    LoggingInit();
    LOG4CPLUS_INFO(root,  "Running as service");
    StartLpaService(); //Here I am creating a service.
    return 0;
}
```

I get following data in the text file created by **WriteToLog** function

```
Logging Init
C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\lpa\\output\\output.log
Loging Init Successful
```

I get the Local App Data Path if the Executable is run as Normal instead of Service.

```
C:\\Users\\logpoint\\AppData\\Local\\
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Which user account are you running the service under? Apparently, it's not `logpoint`; probably `SYSTEM`. The "one true path" is different for each account.

Comment: I came across information that the HKCU can be impersonated using functions like LoadUserProfile(),ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(). Do you have any reference on how to impersonate Current User and get the LocalAppData path for the logged user.

Comment: Which user is "Current User"? At any given time, there can be zero, one or more than one interactive user logged in to a machine where your service is running. Why do you want your service to write files to a user's profile? That's an unusual thing to want to do.

Comment: Current User is the one who installed the MSI.

Comment: Store the path somewhere under `HKLM` at installation time, then.

Comment: Will the executable access ***HLKM*** when it runs as service?

Comment: In case you wonder, `HKLM` is short for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. It's a registry key that doesn't vary per user (unlike `HKCU` aka `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`), and is used to store machine-wide data. It is common to store per-machine application data under `HKLM\Software\<YourCompanyName>\<YourProductName>`; and per-user data under `HKCU\Software\<YourCompanyName>\<YourProductName>`.

Comment: Thanks I did what you suggested. It worked. I have updated the answer. If you could look at it, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for insight given by [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik). I solved the issue by writing the ***LocalAppDataFolder*** path in Registry when I made the wix installer. For this I used:

```
<Component Id="registry_values" Guid="{11FB6C4C-3C90-4F46-B0D2-BB95150F60E6}">
        <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                     Key="Software\Logpoint"
              Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="path" Value="[LocalAppDataFolder]"/>
        </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

Since the Path of Registry written varies for both 64 and 32 bit windows, I did following code to know it:

```
bool DetectWindowsVersionBit()
{
#if defined( WIN64 )
  return true; // 64-bit process running on 64-bit windows
#endif

  BOOL bIsWow64 = false; // must default to FALSE
  typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);
  LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(
    GetModuleHandle("kernel32"), "IsWow64Process");

  if (NULL != fnIsWow64Process)
  {
    if (!fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64))
    {
      //ASSERT( FALSE ); // something went majorly wrong
    }
  }
  return bIsWow64;
}
```

Thus I made my own code for accessing the path. I didn't used **SHGetFolderPath** now. Here it is:

```
std::string GetLocalAppDataPath()
    {
        HKEY hKey;
        char buf[255];
        DWORD dwType;
        DWORD dwBufSize = sizeof(buf);
        std::string ss="";
        const char *subKey;
        bool is64bit =  DetectWindowsVersionBit();
        if(is64bit)
        {
            subKey = "Software\\\\Wow6432Node\\\\Logpoint";
        }
        else
        {
            subKey = "Software\\\\Logpoint";
        }
        WriteToLog(" Inside GetLocalAppDataPath") ;
        if( RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subKey,&hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            WriteToLog("Opened the Registry Key");
        dwType = REG_SZ;
        if( RegQueryValueEx(hKey,"path",0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buf, &dwBufSize) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
        ss = buf;       
        WriteToLog(ss.c_str());
        }
        else
        {
        WriteToLog(" Cound not find the value");

        }           
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
        else
        {
            WriteToLog(" Cannot Open the Local App Data Path");

        }

        return ss;
    }
```

Comment: Are you working for Microsoft? If you don't, you probably shouldn't be writing under `Software\Microsoft` key. It kinda makes me suspicious of your motives.

Comment: Sorry, I was just checking if the Method works or not. I will be updating the Registry with my own path.